# Default ToggleButton of Expander in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, togglebutton, expander

`Expander` should be the `HeaderText` on the left and the `ToggleButton` on right side.

I try to set the `ToggleButton` to the default style, without to create a new completly `ControlTemplate` for it.

Can someone help?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander" x:Key="ExpanderControlx">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="ContentRow" Height="0"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                              OverridesDefaultStyle="True" 
                              Template="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
                              />
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Eddie.TextFormat="Header1" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Name="ContentText" >
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentRow" Property="Height" Value="{Binding ElementName=ContentText, Path=Height}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="controls:ExpanderControl">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource  ExpanderControlx}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I try to set the Template of the ToggleButton to the Static Resource of ToggleButton, but I got an error.

Comment: How does the ToggleButton currently look like and how do you expect it to look?

Comment: So you want the whole row to be a Toggle button but have the visual for the Toggle just be on the right hand side? It's unclear what you're asking, sounds like a quick template though.

Comment: The Togglebutton should look like the default button of an normal extender. Only the field of the upper rights side should have the normal extender button.  If i delete in the code the row of allocation to the override template of the togglebutton, it show a rectangular button with no arrow.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I think you are looking for an Expander whose header is on the left and arrow button (toggle) on the right.

[image]

If so, you could use the Expander from Material Design toolkit linked [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Expander.xaml).

You could also explore more of the Material Design toolkit [here](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/).